# Are unbound result sets more performant than a query with joins when used with IN clause?

Tags: sql-server, performance

With a subquery within the IN clause, am I better off returning a large number of results (10,000+ rows) or using table joins to restrict the results?

For example:

```
select * from Units u
  inner join pm_Properties p on p.PropertyId = u.PropertyId
  where p.State = 'CA'
  and u.UnitId in (select UnitId from Leases l where l.IsActive = 1)
```

vs

```
select * from Units u
  inner join pm_Properties p on p.PropertyId = u.PropertyId
  where p.State = 'CA'
  and u.UnitId in (select UnitId from Leases l 
    inner join Units u on u.UnitId = l.UnitId 
    inner join Properties p on p.PropertyId = u.PropertyId 
    where l.IsActive = 1 and p.State = 'CA')
```

In both cases, I do want to return unit results joined with properties.  I'm just curious about the performance difference regarding the IN statement.  Additionally, if it matters, the server is MS SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Please get in the habit of prefixing all of your column references, even if they currently can only come from one table. "`and UnitId in`" should be "`and unit.UnitId in`" or "`and Units.UnitId in`" - it may be obvious to you now, but later when someone else is troubleshooting, they have to reverse engineer... never mind if you add more tables to the query, you will have to go back and prefix anyway if any of the new tables have the same column name.

Comment: (Sorry, if I'm going to preach about best practices, I can't leave this one out - you don't really push SELECT * to production, do you?)

Comment: @aaron thanks for the suggestions.  I have cleaned up the sample code

Comment: @aaron no, the sql code in my program is largely abstracted away from me with an ORM and it specifies each column explicitly.  The select * is just quicker to write here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first one (unless you have performance problems for some reason).

The second one is just supplying redundant information that SQL server will be able to work out for itself - all you have done is increase the complexity of the query increasing the cost of working out the execution plan and increasing the chances that it won't be able to find the optimal plan.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way to let the optimizer do its job is to avoid both versions with subqueries. Why not this?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Units AS u
  INNER JOIN pm_Properties AS p
  ON p.PropertyId = u.PropertyId
  INNER JOIN Leases AS l
  ON l.UnitId = u.UnitId
  AND l.IsActive = 1
  WHERE p.State = 'CA';
```

Based on JNK's suggestion, yet another alternative is as follows (but as I suggested, there may be a whole lot of I/O checking for valid leases if there are a large percentage not in CA):

```
SELECT *
    FROM Units AS u
    INNER JOIN pm_Properties AS p
    ON p.PropertyId = u.PropertyId
    WHERE p.State = 'CA'
    AND EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM Leases AS l
         WHERE l.UnitId = u.UnitId
         AND l.IsActive = 1
    );
```

Of course, you know your data, your indexes, your hardware, your usage patterns, etc. The *most effective* way to determine which route you're "better off" with is to test them yourself - this will give you a more reliable answer than anyone you can ask here. No offense to anyone, but there are too many variables to be able to make a blanket statement.

Also - and this is just a nit - what is the point of making a table alias Units -> unit? You typed 4 extra characters to avoid typing one - which might make sense if you planned to reference Units more than 4 times in the query, but especially in that case I would rather make a shorter alias.

Comment: In my experience if you aren't returning any fields from the table, an `IN` or `EXISTS` subquery is faster for things like this...It also avoids issues with duplicate rows in your `JOIN`ed table causing dupes in your output

Comment: In this case, I might agree with you but the simpler IN version as written in the question has the potential to materialize a WHOLE LOT of leases that aren't in California. Again why I updated my question with an "it depends" disclaimer on schema, indexes, data...

Comment: yep agreed.  There's no answer for every case.  I think we need a keyboard shortcut for **IT DEPENDS** to be added to the SO GUI.

Comment: @gbn, I assumed (and the op confirmed) that they aren't actually using SELECT *. So if the actual desired columns are expressed correctly, they won't be different queries.

Answer (score 0):

As JNK implied, it depends.

It depends on how complex your join conditions must be, and how many rows each table has relative to the other tables.  I think in a "normal" situation your first example without the joins inside the IN clause will be faster, but that will vary by the factors I mentioned.

So, if you are really trying to absolutely optimize performance, I would test them both, and put whichever comes out better for your particular situation into production.  But, if they were even close I would strongly prefer the first one (which I think will win in most use cases anyway).  It is easier for the optimizer to work with and more importantly it is easier to read which means it will be easier to maintain.